# My 6S screen has gone black. What do I do?

Tags: iphone

My 6S screen has gone black.

How do I reset the display functionally?

Comment: Reset? Reset what? Is your data backed up anywhere?

Comment: What exactly is your question here: how to backup an iPhone with a non-working display, how to recover display functionality, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If the screen stays black after a reboot it's most likely a hardware issue. If you still have warranty or Apple Care reach out to Apple to have it fixed. Otherwise you can try an independent repair center.